# Failed to start Samba SMB Daemon Raspbian Buster Pi3

Tags: raspbian, samba

I updated Jessie Raspbian to Strectch then Buster (Debian 10) on Pi3
Samba was ok on Jessie but does not work anymore due to Failed to start Samba SMB Daemon
when I want to start smbd service, below the message:

```
Active: failed (result: core-dump)
Process: 1466 ExactStart=/usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no-process-group $SMBDOPTIONS (code=dumped, signal=SEGV)
```

Thanks for your help

smb.conf:

```
[global]
 workgroup=WORKGROUP
 server string = %h
 security=user
[GROIX]
 comment = HDD shared with group @partage
 path="/media/GROIX"
 browseable=yes
 read only=no 
 writable=yes 
 valid users=@partage
 create mask = 0750
 directory mask = 0750
```

Comment: I'm amazed you got it to boot - my early attempts of Stretch to Buster died spectacularly!  Have you checked you have only current / valid commands in the Samba config - the updates may have changed the programs but not touched the configs.

Comment: here my smb.conf: [global] workgroup=WORKGROUP server string = %h security=user [GROIX] comment = HDD shared with group @partage path="/media/GROIX" browseable=yes read only=no writable=yes valid users=@partage create mask = 0750 directory mask = 0750

Comment: Bar from the odd `read only = no' inferring 'writable=yes` then my guess is Samba or one of the requirements / precursors has not upgraded correctly.  I would **BACKUP THE SD CARD ** un-install / purge and re-install from fresh. `sudo apt update` then `sudo apt remove --purge samba` then maybe `sudo apt autoremove` then 'sudo apt install samba` This assumes you do not have the Samba client installed on the Pi.

Comment: have you tried to remove & re-install Samba using apt?

Comment: I removed samba and reinstalled it with the same result.

Answer (score 2):

You should not expect that an upgrade from an upgrade works as noted at [Updating and upgrading Raspbian](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/updating.md):

> Upgrading an existing Jessie image is possible, but is not guaranteed to work in every circumstance. If you wish to try upgrading a Jessie image to Stretch, we strongly recommend making a backup first — we can accept no responsibility for loss of data from a failed update.

You should better start with a new Raspbian Buster image.